# Should fields still be private when you need to restructure the data?

Tags: object-oriented

I was taught that an object should know how to do everything with itself. So I've built an application trying to keep fields private and have a lot of methods like these:

- DisplayGraphically()
- DisplayAsText()
- WriteToFile()
- Apply()
- Edit() (shows a dialog box to edit it)
- ErrorCheck()

Now I want to save the data to another file format whose structure doesn't closely correspond to my object structure. It would feel easy if all the data was public. Then a single method could collect all the various bits of data from the objects and reorganize it to suit the file format. But this means exposing private fields (through getters). On the other hand, that's what an API would provide and surely doing this job through an API would be quite clean.

To sum up, which is better in what cases?

1. Fields are private. Objects have lots of methods to deal with many different uses.
2. Fields have public getters and setters which maintain correct internal state. New functionality that involves many objects can be encapsulated in its own class and doesn't require any modification of the existing code.

Comment: Take a step back. Perhaps I/O should not be ingrained into your object to begin with? It might be better if you create something like a "persistence strategy" that knows how to take an object of type X and convert it to format Y. This does not really answer the question as written, but it might be a better design.

Comment: there is also such a thing as SRP single responsible principle. which goes against "should know how to do everything with it self" I would take that with a grain of salt. everything is a balance. nobody said software development is easy :)

Comment: A "reorganize" function implemented outside your class would need to use some accessors that return the necessary data values at a sufficient granularity for it to do its job. This does _not_ necessarily correspond one-to-one with the fields of your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate your *data objects* clearly from other *application's classes*, following the [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principle. Most of the methods from your example should not belong to your data objects, they should belong to controller classes or other application classes, because the responsibility of your data objects should only be, well, to hold or manage their data, and not to interact with the file system or the user interface. If you start to restructure your application that way, your data objects (and only the data objects) will have most of their fields public accessible already.

For example, a method like `DisplayAsText()` which actually *displays* your object on screen does clearly not belong into any of your data objects. Instead, a method like `ToString()` could be part of your data objects, which is called from a method `DisplayAsText()` beeing part of a completely different class somewhere else in your application. A method like `ErrorCheck` could call a lot of small validation methods of your data objects telling if some state is right or wrong, and display the error, which means, the small validation methods should be part of your data objects, and `ErrorCheck` itself clearly not. And a method like `Edit()` will typically need complete read/write access to every data field of your data objects, so you should already have this available when starting to implement your `SaveToNewFormat` method.

Comment: SRP looks like it will lead to an explosion in the number of classes - a new FileWriter, NewFormatConverter, Editor, etc for each existing data class. Is that something to be concerned about? Same amount of code but separated into several times as many classes.

Comment: @user1318499: you should more be converned about having too few classes (with too many lines of code) than too many if there are so many functionalities in your application. And if applying the SRP to your code leads to "an explosion in the number of classes", then there is something wrong with your code, not with the SRP.

Comment: This answer shows how the overhyped SRP leads to anemic classes.

Comment: @Doc Brown. Just to be sure I'm doing this right. Since most data classes have quite different data (various combinations of text, pictures, lists, doubles, integers, etc), and assuming that's an OK design, then does each data class need its own unique `Editor` class which only has the responsibility of letting the user edit that class's data? All of these would implement a common `IEditable` interface.

Comment: @user1318499: well, I don't know the structure or the use cases of your application, but your comment sounds you are confusing the internal structure of your data with the viewpoint of the user. Both should be mostly independent. An `Editor` should allow to edit exactly the data which is relevant to a certain use case, which can be very different from how the data objects are structured.

Comment: @user949300: SRP it leads to data objects with core business functionality (and if you had read my answer carefully, you had noted I had already give some examples for methods belonging into the "domain model", which is quite the opposite of an anemic model). The examples the OP gave seem to be examples of domain objects containing IO and user interface functionality, which should be clearly separated from the domain model.

Comment: Your list of acceptable domain model methods are some validation methods and `toString()`.  Period.  That is anemic.  In your defense, we don't really know OP's domain so it is hard to say what else belongs in the domain model.  But having a `toString()` method hardly qualifies as a rich domain model.  And, in my experience, "data objects" are sometimes necessary to send data across layers, but have almost always been painfully anemic and to be avoided where possible.  Maybe your experience differs and I'd love to see better examples where they work.

Answer (score 0):

> Fields are private. Objects have lots of methods to deal with many different uses.

Keep fields private (getters & setters are evil), but also reduce the specific things each object is doing by using other specialized objects.

To give an example no object should have both these methods

```
DisplayGraphically()
DisplayAsText()
```

They should have at most a single display method. It is not the objects job to figure out where they are displaying to. Instead you should have a Display object that does the grunt work and can either be a graphic display or a console display. This class should have a clear interface that the your object expects and understand.

So instead of the two different messages above replace with

```
myobj.display_myself(display_to_use)
```

Your object knows *only* how to use this Display object to display itself, most likely by simply calling the Display object with internal state of the object.

It is the display object itself knows how to display that information. You could have a thousand types of Display classes but your original object still only needs one method.

So say you are saving your objects data to a DB. Your object shouldn't care. It just has

```
myobj.persist_myself(persistence_to_use)
```

where persistence_to_use can be an object that knows how to write to a database, or an object that knows about files, or an object that knows about back up tape disks etc.

You want to completely change the file format you use to persist your data. Great, your object doesn't care a bit. You simply create a new Persistence object that does what ever new fancy file system stuff you want and pass that object instead of your old persistence object. *myobj* doesn't even notice this change.

Comment: `Your object knows only how to use this Display object to display itself` The display code should depend on the object, not the other way around. Drawing a circle is one of infinitely many things you may choose to do or not to do with it, and a circle is not defined by whether its ability to accept some abstract Display to draw itself to. The inclusion of non-essential operations is a subtle violation of the Interface Segregation Principle (because not everyone needs to draw circles) and Dependency Inversion Principle (because changes to the higher level display API breaks your circle).

Comment: +1 for "getters and setters are evil".  When designing, consider what is most likely to change, the Display (hopefully a standard, abstracted component like a Canvas, JPanel, GC) or a business object which marketing is constantly adding fields to?

Comment: @Doval If the display code depends on the object you break encapsulation, because the display only knows what points to draw by ripping the data out of the Circle object ie central point, radius, pi etc. You have just moved the behaviour "Draw a circle" from the Circle to the Display object making the Display object fat with knowledge about circles. ISP does not say that you should have no method unless everyone uses it, it says no one should have to depend on a method or interface they don't want to use. Drawing a circle is a behaviour that exists in the system and thus makes sense in Circle

Comment: @CormacMulhall You're going to have to know the circle's center point and radius no matter where you put the display code. A circle type should contain enough information to determine its geometry *and no more*. Once you start breaking that rule, you enter a slippery slope of additions. Today you want to draw the circle. Tomorrow you're adding a method to accept an IPersister to store it on a database. Next week you're adding a method to send it over the network. Next month you're adding a method to encode it to JSON. Before you know it, no one but you will want to use your circle type.

Comment: @Doval If you try and produce a universal circle object that can work in any context you are doomed to failure, because a "circle" in one context has different behaviour to a "circle" in another context and OOD is about modelling behaviour not any notion of Platonic forms. The behaviour determine your geometry could be next to useless in say a graphics package. You produce anemic objects that encapsulate no relevant behaviour and then simply shift the actual behaviour some where else in the name of object reuse.

Comment: @CormacMulhall A circle is a circle in any context. The only thing that could possibly change about a circle is how you represent its geometry internally. You might choose to store the center point and diameter and I might choose to store the center point and radius. Your decision will make finding the diameter quicker, mine will make finding the radius quicker. It's still a circle.

Comment: You are talking about data. OOD is about behaviour. What is the behaviour of a circle, what can it do, will depend on what context you mean "circle". Your Platonic circle cannot do anything, it is just the data resulting from a mathematical relationship. As such it isn't an object to begin with.

Comment: @CormacMulhall OOD is not about behavior, it's about objects; and the point of objects is abstraction, the hiding of implementation details. I don't need to know how you're representing your circle internally as long as I can get at its center and radius *somehow*. You can choose to store its data in a `char` array for all I care. Your claim that you can stuff arbitrary methods into a type "because it exists in the system" is anti-modular. You advocate modifying objects every time the system grows.

Comment: Objects are units of work. They are defined by what they do, ie their behaviour. They do not exist to shield representational details of data from other areas of the code, that is not at all the purpose of OOD. Also you do not stuff "arbitrary" methods into an object, you put methods relevant to the objects behaviour into the object. If you grow your system you do not add methods (since these objects are already defined by what they do) you instead add new objects that encapsulate the new behaviours added to the system. Anyway we have gone quite far off the original topic.

Comment: @Doval, assuming we do the minimal circle, are you proposing separate classes for CircleDrawer, CircleDBPersister, CircleXMLer, perhaps with relevant factories?  *That* violates SRP.  (Sometimes it would be the correct design, not always)  CircleDrawer has two reasons to change, if you change the graphics library, or if Circle changes, say, it gains a non-geometric property like color.  Your scheme requires a CircleColor, CirclePattern, etc...  Obviously, I'm exaggerating some but these things do happen and lead to a Kingdom of the Nouns.

Comment: @user949300 You shouldn't put a non-geometric property in a type representing a geometric shape, so that's a moot point. *Every* type breaks when its dependencies break, so by your definition of SRP, you can never have a single reponsibility. In reality, SRP is about the responsibilities of the current type, and a CircleDrawer only has one reason to change - you change how you draw things. In fact, a minimal circle type is incredibly stable, unlike Cormac's approach where the circle's API changes as the system finds new uses for circles.